# How to write a date range condition

Tags: date, date-range

How would I write the date range condition correctly for the following query: list all instruments from table "asset", where the "maturity_dt" > 1 year:...
in English it sounds like :" AND asset.maturity_dt >= Today + 365.."

Comment: Consider mentioning your table structure when you ask a DBMS question and also mention relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you will be needing a query like,

```
Select * from asset where DATEDIFF(maturity_dt, now())>365;
```